# How to make the LED in USB stick blink only when accessed?

Tags: 11.10, server, mount, usb-drive

In Ubuntu with GUI I plug the flash drive into usb port, and is automatically mounted, the LED turns on and off the thumb drive that is to be checked. In ubuntu server (text mode, without GUI) I connect the pen drive is checked and the same non-stop, not for your LED blinking, even after mounting the pen drive the LED continues to blink.

Could someone tell me how do I mount the pen drive on ubuntu server, but with the same settings of the graphical ubuntu-desktop? Actually I want to do the same on ubuntu server configurations mounting pen drive ubuntu-desktop or flash drive that led to only stay lit when it is accessed.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is marked for closure. Regards,

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!